# Adding Transition is changing the positions set by Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Ok, so this example is working fine if I am not adding transition property to the `.slide` class. If I add this transition property, then the `right` property set through jquery is not working as expected. It is adding or subtracting too much.

here is the code:

```js
$(function(){
  $("#with-transition").click(function() {
    $(document.body).toggleClass("with-transition", this.value);
  }).trigger("click");
  var curSlide = 0;
  $('.arrow-left').click(function(){
  
  var $slideContainer = $('.slides');
  var $slide = $slideContainer.find('.slide');
  
  curSlide++;
  if(curSlide === $slide.length){
    $slide.css({"right":"-=200%"});
    curSlide = 0;
  } else {
    $slide.css({"right":"+=100%"});
  } 
});
})
```

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #efefef;
  position: relative;
}

.container {
  width: 600px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #17A05E;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
          transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.slides {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
body.with-transition .slide {
  -webkit-transition: all 400ms ease-in;
  transition: all 400ms ease-in;
}
.slide1, .slide2, .slide3 {
  width: 600px;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
}

.slide1 {
  background-color: #DD4E42;
  right: -200%;
}

.slide2 {
  background-color: #DF6026;
  right: -100%;
}

.slide3 {
  background-color: #F1990D;
  right: 0;
}

.nav {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
  z-index: 1000;
}
.nav .arrow-left, .nav .arrow-right {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
  transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
}
.nav .arrow-left {
  left: 0;
}
.nav .arrow-right {
  right: 0;
}

.arrow-left:hover, .arrow-right:hover {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
}
```

```html
<label><input type="checkbox" id="with-transition"> Include transition</label>
<div class="container">
  <div class="slides">
    <div class="slide slide1"></div>
    <div class="slide slide2"></div>
    <div class="slide slide3"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="nav">
    <div class="arrow-left"></div>
    <div class="arrow-right"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The transition takes place when you click the lighter orange box on the lower left side. In order to check the difference, try it both with and without the checkbox ticked, which determines whether the transition is included. Now, what I want is, how to make this code work with transition exactly the way it is working without transition.

Here I am adding the snapshot of inspect element:
1) - Without Transition
[image: This is without transition]

2) - With Transition
[image: THis is without Transition]

And finally here is the Pen:[Check it out here as well](http://codepen.io/malinaeemi/pen/YWRKYA)

Comment: I recreated the issue. It was a problem with jquery version.
Below 2.2.4 version of jquery, the issue is not showing properly even though change is same in the inspect element (i.e. moving element -1100px).

Comment: Bizarre. I can see the behavior now. No idea what's causing it. :-)

Comment: ok, so when I am using pixels instead of percentage in the value..it is working fine...but it kind of kills the idea -_-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I couldn't fix this issue with percentage. If I use pixels instead of percentage in the right property then it works fine with the transition otherwise it adds too much to the right property.

But what I did now was used `transform: translate(x,y)` property to tackle the situation.

It works as intended and the way I wanted it to. Besides to move it relative to its positions I made a new variable called `xPos` and gave it a value of `100` and used this var in my translate (x) property.

Here is the Jquery of this newer version:

```
$(function(){
  var curSlide = 0;
  var xPos = 100;
  $('.arrow-left').click(function(){

    var $slideContainer = $('.slides');
    var $slide = $slideContainer.find('.slide');

    curSlide++;
    if(curSlide === $slide.length){
      $slide.css({'transform':'translate('+(xPos-xPos)+'%, 0)'});
      curSlide = 0;
      xPos = 100;
    } else {
      $slide.css({'transform':'translate(-'+xPos+'%, 0)'});
      xPos = xPos + 100;
    } 
 });
});
```

Although again, if anyone know why this bizzare behavior was occurring when I use percentage on the right property along with the css transition, I would be more than happy to know!